# PHP convert days to progressive dateTime

Tags: php, function, date

May be a simple question, but if I have a date say 3rd of December. How could I use php to get that date in a date time format with the current year?

so for 2016 it will be 2016-12-03
and 2017 2017-12-03.

I have a function that needs to calculate the next payment date, and would need to work without magic strings

Comment: Use $datetime->format('Y') method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `DateTime` object. You get the current year i.e. with the `date`-function. Or you could also use the DateTime Object again `(new DateTime())->format('Y')`

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setDate(date('Y'), 12, 3);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```